# Does it help my team's gym if I train there, but lose?

Tags: pokemon-go

In my neighborhood, there is a gym currently under control of my team (Team Instinct-Yellow) where all the Pokémon have 1000+ CP. I just started playing the game yesterday and the highest level Pokémon I have so far is 135 CP, so I have no chance of winning.

I read that training can help a friendly gym by having it gain prestige. Does it help my team's gym if I train there, but lose? Or do I have to actually win?

Comment: there is no team insight, do you mean instinct?

Comment: @Pyritie didn't even see that in the question the first time I read it haha! #Valor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You actually have to beat atleast 1 pokemon in the gym to get some prestige. If you can't beat any of them then you won't get any prestige at that gym.

Comment: Can you choose who to fight at the gym? How?

Comment: @pjc50 You can not choose who to fight at a gym. You battle against the pokemon with the lowest CP and work your way up.

Comment: @Kiwi Does that also mean your gym gets more prestige per win as you train your way up the board?

Comment: @KizTrap I think so, in my experience I beat 2/3 pokemon and kept getting 200 prestige. So I assume it will be 300 if not more if I would have beaten all 3.

Answer (score 2):

I just checked this out tonight.  I lost several battles to much stronger Pokemon at a friendly gym.  There was no change in point value for any of my Pokemon or trainer and no change in prestige for the gym.

The only value might be to get some idea of how to battle and to learn something about which Pokemon might be most effective against another type of Pokemon. You can get feedback during the battle of very effective or not very effective although the battle will be very short against a much stronger opponent.